# how to set brightness in Chromebook with external screen

Tags: chrome-os, chrome-book

I have connected my Acer Chromebook to external screen and keyboard. How can I control the display brightness? (the screen does not have its own controls.)
Usually I can click the brightness buttons in the built in keyboard but here I am using an external keyboard and also setting the built-in keyboard brightness only affects the built in screen and not the external one.

Answer (score 1):

From `man xrandr`:

```
      --brightness brightness
          Multiply  the gamma values on the crtc currently attached to the
          output to specified floating value. Useful for overly bright  or
          overly  dim outputs.
```

You would use it like this:

```
xrandr --output <output> --brightness <brightness>
```

First, you need to find the name of the output:

```
xrandr -q
```

There should be several results displayed, with at least two of those marked "connected". My external VGA screen is called "DP1".

For brightness values, "1" is default; "2" is extra bright, "0.5" is dim-ish.

So for me, the command for a little extra brightness looks like this:

```
xrandr --output DP1 --brightness 1.2
```

Comment: how to run this command? do I need to be in developer mode? corsh does not recognize it

Comment: Yes, you would need to enter developer mode, then enter the command `shell`, which should give you a full bash shell (and hopefully  `xrandr`)

Comment: It has been rather a while since ChromeOS offered `xrandr`. It uses wayland now. There is no known solution to the brightness problem.